# Horizontal menu bar moves a bit to the left because of scroll bar to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this web application that manages a DB.
Everytime I go to this certain page that has a big list, the vertical scroll bar appears on the right side of the browser.

That, however, makes my whole page move to the side by a bit.
It is most noticeable if you look at the horizontal menu bar I have at the top of the page.

Is there anyway to overcome this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the scrollbar to always be shown by applying the following to you body: `overflow-y:scroll;`

Answer (score -3):

```
body
{
    background:#DDDDDD;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```